# How do I concatenate two variables as my ng-src?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a variable from my controller which has a link, and a picture from my ng-repeat.

```
vm.data.piclink = 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/felda/'; 
// in my controler


//in my html
<div ng-repeat =" picturename in category.category_name_image" >
    <image type="image" ng-src= "category.data.piclink" + "picturename.picture[0].filename" style="width:100%" />
//picturename.picture[0].filename = u_backpack.png
</div>
```

Im not sure how to combine the two to become one whole link. I want my result to come out like this: https//3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/felda/u_backpack.png

Comment: `ng-src= "{{category.data.piclink + picturename.picture[0].filename}}"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ng-src="{{category.data.piclink + picturename.picture[0].filename}}"
```